# How to use Sweet alert on Bootstrap 4 alert which is using in a PHP application

Tags: php, bootstrap-4, sweetalert

I use bootstrap alert to show alert message on user activity in my php app. Now I want to implement sweet alert so how Can I properly replace this to work?
bellow is my `messages.php`

```
  <?php if (isset($_SESSION['success_msg'])): ?>
      <div id="success-alert" class="alert <?php echo 'alert-success'; ?> alert-dismissible" role="alert">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <?php
          echo $_SESSION['success_msg'];
          unset($_SESSION['success_msg']);
        ?>
      </div>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php if (isset($_SESSION['error_msg'])): ?>
      <div id="danger-alert" class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible" role="alert">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <?php
          echo $_SESSION['error_msg'];
          unset($_SESSION['error_msg']);
        ?>
      </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

**How I can use this ?**

```
//Success Message
    Swal.fire(
        {
            title: 'Success!',
            text: 'Updated successfully!',
            type: 'success',
            confirmButtonColor: "#58db83",
           
        }
    )  
    
    //Error Message
    Swal.fire(
        {
            title: 'Failed!',
            text: 'Something went Wrong!',
            type: 'warning',
            confirmButtonColor: "#58db83",
            
        }
    )
```

```js
//Error Message
        $('#sa-title').click(function () {
                Swal.fire(
                    {
              icon: 'error',
              title: 'Your work has failed to saved',
              showConfirmButton: true,
              timer: 2000
                    }
                )
        });

        //Success Message
        $('#sa-success').click(function () {
           Swal.fire(
              {
                icon: 'success',
                title: 'Your work has been saved',
                showConfirmButton: true,
                timer: 2000
              }
            )
        });
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@9.17.1/dist/sweetalert2.min.css">



 <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 m-b-30">
        <p class="text-muted">A Error Message</p>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary waves-effect waves-light" id="sa-title">Click me</button>
    </div>
    
    
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 m-b-30">
        <p class="text-muted">A success message!</p>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary waves-effect waves-light" id="sa-success">Click me</button>
    </div>
</div>  





<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B4gt1jrGC7Jh4AgTPSdUtOBvfO8shuf57BaghqFfPlYxofvL8/KUEfYiJOMMV+rV" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@9.17.1/dist/sweetalert2.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have successfully added this to my app
My php file i have edited like

```
<?php if (isset($_SESSION['success_msg'])): ?>
  <div id="success-message">
      <p class="text-white"><?php  echo $_SESSION['success_msg'];?></p>
      <?php  unset($_SESSION['success_msg']); ?>
  </div>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php if (isset($_SESSION['error_msg'])): ?>
  <div id="danger-message">
      <p class="text-white"><?php echo $_SESSION['error_msg'];?></p>
    <?php   unset($_SESSION['error_msg']);?>
  </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

And JS code

```
//Success Message
if ($("#success-message").length > 0) {
    var textMsG = $('#success-message > .text-white').text();

    Swal.fire(
        {
            title: 'Success!',
            text: textMsG,
            type: 'success',
            confirmButtonColor: "#58db83",

        }
    )
}

//Error Message
if ($("#danger-message").length > 0) {
    var textMsG = $('#success-message > .text-white').text();

    Swal.fire(
        {
            title: 'Failed!',
            text: textMsG,
            type: 'error',
            confirmButtonColor: "#58db83",

        }
    )
}
```